# Excel 2007 How do I get rid of the 0 (zero) in this formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have dates in columns `U,X,AA,AD,AG and AJ` and Names in `V,Y,AB,AE,AH and AK`. I have the following formula to select the latest updates as they are updated. Columns U and V will be filled first and then columns X and Y are updated at a later date. I need both the date and name column to be filled before the cells in another worksheet are updated.

This is the formula I am using, which is very long, but I can't work out how to make it shorter. For the date I am swapping the columns for the date column (U,X,AA,AD,AG and AJ)in the second half of the formula

> =CHOOSE(1+COUNT('Training Schedule'!U42,'Training Schedule'!V42,'Training Schedule'!X42,'Training
>   Schedule'!Y42,'Training Schedule'!AA42,'Training
>   Schedule'!AB42,'Training Schedule'!AD42,'Training
>   Schedule'!AE42,'Training Schedule'!AG42,'Training
>   Schedule'!AH42,'Training Schedule'!AJ42,'Training
>   Schedule'!AK42),"",'Training Schedule'!V42,'Training
>   Schedule'!Y42,'Training Schedule'!AB42,'Training
>   Schedule'!AE42,'Training Schedule'!AH42,'Training Schedule'!AK42)

This formula works but if no entry is made in the name column a 0 (zero) is copied into the name column. How do I get it to show a blank cell? If I add a name but no date nothing is copied across. I have another formula to count the date and name formula to copy into another worksheet, but it is counting the 0 as if the cell if filled. I have made so many versions of the file I'm working with and have mistakenly deleted my original which used to work with no 0 and I can't remember how I did it!

Answer (score 1):

If you are only putting names in columns `V,Y,AB,AE,AH and AK` then you don't need those cells in the `COUNT` function (names won't be counted by `COUNT` function, it only counts numbers), so you can reduce the size of the formula by removing those....and as you are returning text values you can simply concatenate a "null string" to the end of the formula to convert zero to blank if the relevant name cell is blank, so try this version

`=CHOOSE(1+COUNT('Training Schedule'!U42,'Training Schedule'!X42,'Training Schedule'!AA42,'Training Schedule'!AD42,'Training Schedule'!AG42,'Training Schedule'!AJ42),"",'Training Schedule'!V42,'Training Schedule'!Y42,'Training Schedule'!AB42,'Training Schedule'!AE42,'Training Schedule'!AH42,'Training Schedule'!AK42)&""`

You may be able to reduce the size of the formula further - what type of values will be in the intermediate cells `W42, Z42, AC42, AF42 and AI42`, numbers, text, something else? For example, **as long as those intermediate cells don't contain numbers or dates** you could use this shortened version:

`=CHOOSE(1+COUNT('Training Schedule'!U42:AJ42),"",'Training Schedule'!V42,'Training Schedule'!Y42,'Training Schedule'!AB42,'Training Schedule'!AE42,'Training Schedule'!AH42,'Training Schedule'!AK42)&""`

or

`=IF('Training Schedule'!U42="","",INDEX('Training Schedule'!V42:AK42,COUNT('Training Schedule'!U42:AJ42)*3-2)&"")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to almost duplicate your already quite long formula:
    `=if(isblank(<put your old formula here>),"",<put your old formula here>)`

Answer (score 0):

As you've figured out, the formula is returning `0` if the cell it wants to return is blank. There are a few ways to go about changing this depending on what you need. The most common method for "return the value unless it's blank and then be blank" is to wrap the whole thing in an `IF` statement but that doubles the length.

```
=IF([MESS]=0,"",[MESS])
```

If you were trying to return a numeric value, you could use the trick below to avoid having the messy formula twice. However, I think you're trying to return names and it doesn't work with strings.

```
=IFERROR(1/1/[MESS],"")
```

However, if you don't care about the zero being there so long as nobody can see it, I'd recommend using conditional formatting to set the font color to be the same as the background. The cell will still contain the value `0` but it won't be seen on the screen or in a printout.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I appreciate the first two options, but not the third one - My previous boss used to do this - change all fonts to white and they become visible when you highlight / select those cells

Comment: @Prasanna You're right that, in general, it's better to make cells be actually blank instead of just appearing blank. However, if OP is using this for a final report or dashboard (i.e., no other cells reference the one in question), it truly doesn't matter. The only people who will know it's there are the administrators of the document.

Comment: Does my answer - contradict with my own statement? .... :-(    Oops

Comment: I do have a formula associated with these cells.  The formula counts the entries if both boxes are filled and then puts them in another worksheet.  I need to be able to ignore both entries if one cell is blank.  I am struggling with the IF formula as I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If this file is going to be dedicated for this purpose - changing an option in excel would be helpful - rather than add a formula to hide the available zero.
[image]

If you uncheck the marked option - then the file will automatically stop showing values in which result is `0`.

Comment: This would be better but my formula =IF(COUNTBLANK(B19:C19)>0,"",1+MAX($D$1:D18)) to count the entries still picks up there is a 0.  Is there anyway round this?

Comment: Then how about trying the answer from @Engineer Toast - the first option?